# Python: function takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)

Tags: python, function, parameters

My function is as follows using python:

```
def PlotCurve(SourceClipName,mode,TestDetails,savepath='../captures/',**args):

    curves=[]
    for a in range(0,len(args)):
        y=[]
        for testrates in TestDetails.BitratesInTest:

            stub = args[a].Directory[testrates]
            y.append(args[a].DataSet[stub][0])
            curves.append(y)

    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel("Bitrate")
    plt.ylabel(mode)
    plt.title(TestDetails.HDorSD+" "+TestDetails.Codec + " " + SourceClipName[:-4])
    colour=["green","red","brown","orange","purple","grey","black","yellow","white",]
    CurveIDs=[]
    for x in args:
        CurveIDs.append(args.ID)
    p=[]    
    for b in range(0,len(args)-1):
        p[b].plot(TestDetails.BitratesInTest,y[b],c=colour[b])

    plt.legend((p),(CurveIDs),prop={"size":8})
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(savepath,mode+"_"+TestDetails.codec+"_"+SourceClipName[:-4]+".png"))
```

The error specifically is

```
TypeEror: PlotCurve() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

`**args` is a list of objects that has been passed into the function

It appears to me that I have defined a function which accepts 5 or more arguments (regardless of whether it works properly or not), but the program disagrees, what is it I am missing which makes the function think it can only have at most 4 parameters?

Comment: Use `*args`, not `**kwargs`.

Comment: You have defined a function that takes four arguments, plus an unlimited number of key/value arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `*args`, not `**kwargs` (or `**anything`), *or* call the function with parameter names. This will result in a variadic list of the overflow parameters which can then be iterated as done to extract the IDs.

Arguments *must* be specified by name to apply toward `**kwargs` and not the parameter count.

---

See [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

> You would *use *args when you're not sure how many arguments might be passed to your function*, i.e. it allows you pass an arbitrary number of arguments to your function ..  Similarly, ***kwargs allows you to handle named arguments* that you have not defined in advance.

Comment: My problem with trying to use *args as opposed to **args is that it results in the function saying that none of the variables that are within each object in each position of the list exist(which I require).Can you tell me if this is a symptom of *args that means it doesn't allow you to pass a list of objects in or whether there is a more inherent problem with the code?

Comment: @yellowlemming How is the function be called? Inside the function, `*args` *is* a list. To apply a list to a function call, use the converse `f(*args)` form. But it may be better just to take a list as a separate discrete (named) parameter.

Comment: The function is being called in the form `PlotCurve(filename,"MS_SSIM",TestDetails,"../captures/",CurveList[2:3])` and different calls use different parts of the list CurveList so it would be difficult to name the list explicitly.

Comment: Simply take an additional parameter then - a list. `def PlotCurve(clipName, mode, testDetails, savepath='../captures/', curve=[])`. The use of \*args is for a *variadic* number of arguments.

Comment: Thankyou, not sure how I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

When you say, `**args is a list of objects that has been passed into the function`, then it's with single `*`

When you define a function with `**args` as one of the argument it will fail to unpack, while you pass key-value pair

`**kwargs` to be mapped with `dictionary`

`*args` to be mapped with `list`

or you can have them both, as,

```
>>> def func(argone, *args, **kwargs):
>>>    # do stuff
>>>
>>> func(1, *[1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> func(1, *[1, 2, 3, 4], **{'a': 1, 'b': 2})
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you double typed `*`, as convenience for naming optional positional arguments is `*args` and optional named arguments is `**kwargs`.

So your function actually accepts 4 *positional* arguments and arbitrary number of `keyword arguments`. If you call it like this:

```
PlotCurve(1,2,3,4,5) # you should get error
PlotCurve(1,2,3,4,aaa=5) # you should have args = {'aaa': 5}
```

To fix this, most likely you need to remove second star.